# storing big integer in mongo db

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I have a rails app and one of my tables has a big integer key in mysql. I am looking to archive some of the data from the mysql table in mongodb, but am not sure which type to use in field statement within mongoid to store the orignal_id, I have no intention to change the id that mongoid will generate, I am not looking to change the _id field of the new table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your only choice for numeric values in JavaScript is Number. The largest integer that can safely be represented is: 9007199254740991. According to the mysql docs, the maximum bigint is 9223372036854775807, twice that if unsigned.

Maybe you should save it as a string if it's important to maintain fidelity.

Comment: if I were to save it as a string how do you ensure that 10000 comes after 2000, the old id is really being stored because it is referenced in other tables, but order is still important

Comment: @JeffRossi Pad it with `0`s to the largest number of digits which can be expected.

Comment: zero padding was the same idea I had after posting

Answer (score 2):

If you are using mongoid you can define the field as integer. Integers are instance objects of a Fixnum or a Bignum class in Ruby. If any operation on a Fixnum exceeds its range, the value is automatically converted to a Bignum.

Answer (score 0):

I do not use rails, but NumberLong may exist in Rails too. This is a wrapper for 64bit integers. With a unique index you may have similar results, as in MySQL.